# Electrostatic Pummeler with Animation Module

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you use [Electrostatic Pummeler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElectrostatic%20Pummeler%5d)'s ability to turn him into a 2/2 and then you use [Animation Module](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnimation%20Module%5d) to add an additional +1/+1 counter. Would both of those +1/+1 counters be removed at the end of turn or only one?

Comment: This question assumes '+1/+1' is equal to a (temporary) '+1/+1' counter. That is a misconception, but it's not a duplicate of the question linked.. The duped question has never entered OP's mind.

Comment: @steenbergh You may see that duplicate's description is "This question already has an answer here". And this question is indeed answered there.
The duped question hasn't entered OP's mind, but that's the issue they actually have. Had OP knew that question and it's answer, they wouldn't ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electrostatic Pummeler has no ability that puts +1/+1 counters on it. Its second ability modifies its power and toughness until end of turn, and Animation Module's first ability does not trigger.

Comment: AM = Animation module as per question title.